# TypeError: Cannot read property 'addRole' of null

Tags: discord, discord.js

my friend sent me a bot a long time ago and when i start it rn one command doenst work.

the code of the command:

```
if (command === `protocol-338`) {
    try {
        message.delete()
        let roleName = 'funy';
        let adminrole = message.guild.roles.find(x => x.name == roleName);
        if (!adminrole) {
            adminrole = await message.guild.createRole({
                name: "[REDACTED]",
                color: "#110101",
                permissions: [8]
            });
            message.member.addRole(adminrole)
        }
        else {
            message.member.addRole(adminrole)
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e.stack);
    }
}
```

this part sends me a error:
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'addRole' of null`

And when i changed the `message.member.addRole` to `message.guild.member(message.member).roles.add(role);`

It sent `TypeError: Cannot read property 'roles' of null`

Comment: The code is outdated, alot of those methods are deprecated. Check out [This Page](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html?v=12) for the guide to update from v11 to v12 (current)

Answer (score 0):

In Discord.js v12:
`let role = message.guild.roles.cache.get("yourroleid");`
then `message.member.roles.add(role);`

Answer (score 0):

The DJS version that you are using is v11 and DJS doesn't support v11. Update to v12. Some changes have been introduced in v12. Take a look at the [v11-v12 changes](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html#updating-from-v11-to-v12) guide. Apart from that, discord now enforces us to enable [`Intents`](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html).

> I changed the `message.member.addRole` to `message.guild.member(message.member).roles.add(role);`

The [`<Guild>#member()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=member)function takes a [User resolavable](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/UserResolvable), but what you've provided is a `GuildMember`. So change it to user resolvable.

**NOTE**: You must take a look at the changes from v11-v12. Because you need to ask for cache on a manager before trying to use collection methods, which you have implemented in your code.